# Upload file to cloudinary as a stream using phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, upload, stream, cloudinary

I am writing a mobile app using phonegap. The app is supposed to allow the user to take pictures using the device's camera which will be then directly uploaded to cloudinary.

From the camera object from Phonegap API I can get either a base64 encoded stream or a local filename (i.e. file://mnt/sdcard/example.jpg ) when the user takes a photo shoot.

I am familiar with direct uploads against cloudinary from a browser using a file input, however I have not been able to find any documentation on how to upload a file path or a stream of data directly from browser instead of using a file input. I know this can be easily achieved using cloudinary_npm for node.js in server side, so I don't see why I would not be able to do the same in a browser. The problem is cloudinary's jquery plugin does not seem to have any support for this.

My default plan is to use JQuery to try to simulate the same XMLHttpRequest that is getting generated when I use a file input and the cloudinary jquery plugin, however this seems tedious work and I am not sure that this will work.

Any better ideas? Has anyone else tried this before?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [Christophe Coenraets' article on How to upload pictures from a PhoneGap Application to Node.js (and other servers)](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/how-to-upload-pictures-from-a-phonegap-application-to-node-js-and-other-servers-2/).  [Here is the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/ccoenraets/PictureFeed)

Comment: You can also take a look at the Titanium] and Trigger.io integrations:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_titanium
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_triggerio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<input type="file">`, it works for ios >=6 and android != 4.4.

On ios it lets you take a photo/video or pick them from the galley, on android it opens an intent to the gallery or file browsers